# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Unable to Upgrade to PHP 8.0 from PHP 7.2.2

Tags: apache2, php

I have carefully followed guideline provided from these sources: [Upgrade from PHP 7 to 8](https://www.vultr.com/docs/upgrade-from-php-7-to-php-8-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-apache) and [How to install PHP 8 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-php-8-on-ubuntu-20-04). Unfortunately, when I run the command `php -v`
am getting the following output:

```
root@hp-HP-ProBook-6560b:~/parallel# php -v
PHP 7.2.2 (cli) (built: Mar 21 2022 15:00:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
root@hp-HP-ProBook-6560b:~/parallel#
```

What is confusing is that when I try to access localhost from browser the newer PHP version is reflected however on CLI it is showing the older version of PHP. I intend to use the parallels extension which is only available with PHP 8.0.

A screenshot of localhost from browser showing the new version of PHP:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I'm left stuck here:

```
root@hp-HP-ProBook-6560b:~/parallel# sudo ./configure  --host=armv7l --target=armv7l --enable-ssl-crtd  --with-openssl
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-ssl-crtd, --with-openssl
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for armv7l-cc... no
checking for armv7l-gcc... no
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... armv7l-unknown-none
checking target system type... armv7l-unknown-none
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 1.3 (ok)
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable parallel support... yes, shared
checking whether to enable parallel coverage support... no
checking whether to enable parallel developer build flags... no
checking PHP version... configure: error: parallel requires PHP 8.0+
```

I have also tried these these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge php7.*
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

However, `php -v` continues to return `php 7.2.2`.

How can I have a proper PHP 8.0 installation on the command line?

On trying the first suggested solution i'm getting the following as shown on the attached screenshot of cli:

[image: Screenshot of cli]

-Still getting the same result even after trying suggested solutions. I wonder why cli output version 7.2.2 yet when i try to purge it, the response gotten is that the package not found. So how and where does the command php -v get the result of installed php version as 7.2.2 instead of the version 8.0 which is newly installed. See below screenshot:-

[why should command php -v return php7.2.2, yet the package is not found on the system?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nccJI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `update-alternatives` tool may be useful to you here, as you will be able to set specific versions to use.

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (or connect to the server via SSH) if not already done
1. Check the available PHP versions:

   ```
   update-alternatives --list php
   ```

   You may see something like:

   ```
   /usr/bin/php7.2
   /usr/bin/php7.4
   /usr/bin/php8.0
   ```
2. If you see multiple options, you can set the preferred version via the `--config` option:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config php
   ```

   This should give you something like:

   ```
   There are 3 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

   Selection    Path             Priority   Status
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   * 0            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        auto mode
     1            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
     2            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        manual mode
     3            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        manual mode

   Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
   update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.2 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in manual mode
   ```
3. Press <kbd>3</kbd> or the key that corresponds to the version that you would like to run
4. Verify the version is correct:

   ```
   php -v
   ```

   You should now see PHP 8.0 is active.

Comment: Please don't use comments for code snippets. You can [edit] your question to include the additional details, making it possible for other people to offer better/more complete solutions. Have you restarted your machine since eliminating PHP 7.2.2 from the system?

Comment: Yeah. I just restarted my machine. Still no update on php version.